# Simplifying CSS root selector

Tags: html, css

Please refer below css  code

```
#AdminUser .admin-label-margin {
margin-left: 160px;
margin-top: -25px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#AdminUser #entitytitle h4 {
margin-left: 175px;
padding-bottom: 13px;
}
#AdminUser input[type='text'] {
    width: 180px;
}
#AdminUser .admin-label-span {
    margin-left: -15px !important;
    margin-right:12px;
}
```

Each and every time I am specifying the root element and applies the `css` to specific control. I don't want to this kind of scenario. How can i simplify the above `css` and specify root selector in one time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CSS pre-processing library like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which allows you to express your css using nested statements.

So it will allow you to write

```
#AdminUser {
    .admin-label-margin {
    margin-left: 160px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #entitytitle h4 {
        margin-left: 175px;
        padding-bottom: 13px;
    }

    input[type='text'] {
        ...
    }

    .admin-label-span {
        ...
    }
}
```

but once processed it would output the CSS to the browser in the standard non-nested format.  ie. it would generate your original CSS :

```
#AdminUser .admin-label-margin {
margin-left: 160px;
margin-top: -25px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#AdminUser #entitytitle h4 {
margin-left: 175px;
padding-bottom: 13px;
}
#AdminUser input[type='text'] {
    width: 180px;
}
#AdminUser .admin-label-span {
    margin-left: -15px !important;
    margin-right:12px;
}
```

Bear in mind that if you use LESS you have a few considerations :

- running compilation of .less to .css files as part of your build process
- *or* using on the fly conversion with the less javascript

  - you might get FOUC's
  - you'll need to check that your webserver is happy serving the less mime type

On the plus side you'll get mixins, variables and all the goodness that LESS brings you alongside the coding syntax convenience you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

CSS does not support this. You can however use a preprocessor like **[Sass/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/)**.

With SCSS:

```
#AdminUser {
    .admin-label-margin {
        /* snip */
    }
    /* snip */
}
```

Note that the final code will look similar to the original one, SCSS *translates* the above code to the one you currently have, so that you can develop more easily.

Comment: +1 just as a side-note: Sass should be written as "Sass" not "SASS" :)

Answer (score 1):

LESS might be useful:

```
#AdminUser {
    & .admin-label-margin {
        margin-left: 160px;
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: `&` is redundant there. It's useful when it's part of the selector piece (`&:before`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to simplify it in CSS.

You could use a CSS preprocessor language, such as SASS, which would allow you to:

```
#AdminUser {
    .admin-label-margin {
        margin-left:160px;
        margin-top:-25px;
        padding-bottom:10px
    }

    #entitytitle h4 {
        margin-left:175px;
        padding-bottom:13px
    }

    input[type='text'] {
        width:180px
    }

    .admin-label-span {
        margin-left:-15px!important;
        margin-right:12px
    }
}
```